# Is there a way to get Spring variable substitution inside JPA annotation values?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

This works on SQL server:

```
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL CHECK(ISJSON(tags) = 1)")
    private List<String> tags = Lists.newArrayList();
```

But you need to do this on H2:

```
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json")
    private List<String> tags = Lists.newArrayList();
```

Is there a way to use a spring application property:

```
#h2
json_coldef=json

#sql server
json_coldef=NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL CHECK(ISJSON(tags) = 1)
```

so that I can do this?

```
    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "${json_coldef}")
    private List<String> tags = Lists.newArrayList();
```

so that it loads it from a spring property specified at JVM system property?

In other words, is there some way I can use spring variables inside the JPA annotation values and get variable substitution?

Comment: No. As those are processed by JPA and not Spring, so no. What you should do is not let Hibernate manage your schema but rather something like Flyway or Liquibase for which you can have different sql files for different databases.

Comment: schema being managed by hibernate doesn't really bother me here. it's the fact I cannot tell my java app what columnDefinition to use based on dialect. how does liquibase owning the schema help me here?

Comment: The `columnDefinition` is only useful is you let Hibernate manage/create your database schema. If you don't care about that you don't need the `columnDefinition`. Apparently you do care and thus let Hibernate manage your schema (else you wouldn't need it). As it isn't going to work with value substitution you need a different means. With Flyway or Liquibase you can use different SQL files to create your schema based on which database is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from comments: No. JPA annotations cannot use spring substitutions.

So you will need to find a way to **make sure your annotations are completely dialect independent**.

So I went ahead and created this work-around to the issue for now. I will just build my own converter:

```
    /** This is a database independent way to convert pojo to json to database, then back to
     * pojo from database. There is a better way to do this with {@link com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.json.JsonType}, but
     * unfortunately it doesn't work in H2.
     */
    @javax.persistence.Converter
    public static class ListStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {

        @Override
        public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> myCustomObject) {
            try {
                return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myCustomObject);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String databaseDataAsJSONString) {
            try {
                return objectMapper.readValue(databaseDataAsJSONString, List.class);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then use it:

```
@Lob
@Convert(converter = ListStringConverter.class)
private List<String> tags = Lists.newArrayList();
```

It actually performs pretty much the same too. No performance impact that I can tell.

I will remove H2 and replace with **[testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/)** to make this all moot point.